# trying to combine a row into one cell with dates

Tags: excel, cell

ok so im trying to create a macro that will take my set cells and insert them into html code...

what i have is cells with my html code and cells with my values that i need... first it ref. the first html J2 and places it in B13 next it ref. my value that i need and places it in C13 and so on... it gets to a file name that is based off of a date so lets say for date is 6/20/2012 it would take that and format the next cell to pull that date but format the text to go to 20120620.mp3... when the ref. code takes that cell it takes the format... but when i run another script to join all the cells together to one it changes the date to the original format of 6/20/2012... i thought maybe it pulling the original formatting but i changed the original format of the first date cell and it still keeps it in 6/20/2012 format.

```
<div id="messageDate">6/20/2012</div><audio id="audio" preload="none" controls="controls"><source src="sermons_mp3/mp3/6/20/2012" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

it should look like this

```
<div id="messageDate">6/20/2012</div><audio id="audio" preload="none" controls="controls"><source src="sermons_mp3/mp3/20120620.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

im using this code to combine the cells

```
   Sub JoinText()
myCol = Selection.Columns.Count
For i = 1 To myCol
ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) & ActiveCell.Offset(0, i)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, i) = ""
Next i
End Sub
```

and ive tried this one too

```
     Function ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange(sourceRange As Excel.Range) As String
        Dim finalValue As String

        Dim cell As Excel.Range

        For Each cell In sourceRange.Cells
            finalValue = finalValue + CStr(cell.Value)
        Next cell

        ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange = finalValue
    End Function
    Sub MyMacro()
        Range("b14").Select
        ActiveCe

ll.FormulaR1C1 = ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange([b13:r13])
End Sub
```

and all with the same results... i hope this helps and someone can give me some help on this... i am totally new at VBA and have no idea what im doing... what i have done has been me just playing and getting lucky... lol

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you concatenate the date from a cell containing date only (e.g. `6/20/2012` as opposed to `sermons_mp3/mp3/6/20/2012`), you can use following formula to get the src argument:

```
="sermons_mp3/mp3/" & text(date_value, "yyyymmdd") & ".mp3"
```